# Destroying a process in java doesn't closes its associated streams

Tags: java, process, eclipse-rcp, runtime.exec

I'm invoking a external process (say cmd.exe) within my Eclipse RCP application. 
When I start the process, everything seems to be fine and I'm able to run the external process.

However, if I try to exit the process [say by calling the `process.destroy()` API], the process is not exiting still, I'm able to run the commands (like DIR, cls..etc) in my application even after a destroy is called .

This issue is observed only with windows 7 and not in windows 8 or windows 10 OS's.  In windows 8 & 10, I cannot type anything in my view once destroy has been invoked.

Does the destroy() API dependent on the windows platform ??

I believe, that in windows 7, destroy is not clearing the 'output\input' streams associated with it (and that is why I believe I'm still able to execute the commands ).

Does OS has anything to do with clearing streams ?? I'm a bit confused.

Can anyone shed more lights on this ???

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Comment: @AndrewThompson : so, `process` instance is dependent upon the running platform (OS) ?   I'm using `CommandLauncher` API and not `Runtime.exec()`

Comment: *"so, process instance is dependent upon the running platform (OS) ?"* Almost be definition. *"I'm using CommandLauncher API.."* Intriguing. You say that like I should know what it means.. Never heard of that API.